# How can I compile Hazelcast C++ Client with the compiler g++-8.2

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, hazelcast

Is there any solution to make compilation with `g++-8.2` for the project using [*Hazelcast C++ client library*](https://hazelcast.org/clients/cplusplus/) ?

If I compile it with *g++-8.2*, it shows a lot of errors "undefined reference ...".

While using *g++-4.9*, it works well.

The issue is a bit like the discussion in this [google group forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/undefined%7Csort:date/hazelcast/6kYc_mQGQwA/SL8TmR1RaD0J), which indicated the compilation errors are because of the wrong version of a compiler.

However, the compiler *g++-4.9* is too old for me to build my big project.

The sample code can be found in the [official org website](https://hazelcast.org/), if someone needs to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by upgrading the library from 3.10 to 3.11.
The 3.11 library is built manually using `g++-8.2` from [Hazelcast source code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client#table-of-contents)  in Github.

Because there is no `make install` after building *hazelcast-cpp-clienet* package, so I use some scripts to arrange header files together in one directory (`hazelcast-cpp-client/include`) so that a program can easily link the library and headers.

Build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Package Requirements:
#   - asio

mkdir hazelcast-cpp-client ; cd hazelcast-cpp-client

# Build
git clone https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client.git
mv hazelcast-cpp-client tmp
cd tmp
git checkout v3.11
mkdir release ; cd release
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make


# Back to 'hazelcast-cpp-client' directory
cd ../..

# Copy .a library out from tmp/
cp tmp/release/*.a .

# Arrange all header files in an one directory  
cp -r tmp/hazelcast/include .
cp -r tmp/hazelcast/generated-sources/include/hazelcast/client/protocol ./include/hazelcast/client
rm tmp/external/include/*.md # We don't need readme file
cp -r tmp/external/include/* ./include

# Delete tmp directory
rm -rf tmp
```

Compilation command is like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 \
    -I/path/to/hazelcast-cpp-client/include \
    hz_test.cpp \
    /path/to/hazelcast-cpp-client/libHazelcastClient3.11_64.a \
    -lpthread
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this problem. We did not test with the g++-8.2 compiler. I opened an issue to solve the problems: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/issues/494

Can you tell me also your OS environment? What distribution and version is it?

Comment: `OS`: Arch Linux 4.18.12 64bit   `Hazelcast C++ Client version`: 3.10.1